# Patch/Update specific key-value from property list in google drive file metadata

Tags: google-drive-api

So I have these set of properties from my drive. Now I want to update specific key-value pair from the list, but seems like google drive api patch requires another set of properties to be added.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch

```
"properties":[{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/v2QgQs4jWTpXupDwCreIaEqwUB0\"","value":"content_article","key":"TAG_SYSTEM_NAME"},{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/_gkHHQjcY8SsrxQ5YfkEKLgJd78\"","value":"content","key":"TAGSET_SYSTEM_NAME"},{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/zlFg7XikUX87CoN8nlKkxomLGZA\"","value":"1204622","key":"ID"},{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/UP9PtLc4WE_Q7ADNu0V-OSG22QQ\"","value":"1037753","key":"BRIDGE_KM_CON_TAG_GROUP_ID"},{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/sznUVWiSHbLf7-HDsqvfCqoFEpg\"","value":"Content Categories","key":"TAGSET_DISPLAY_NAME"},{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/6F3Yo9Sj6aeMw5BlH7kKSfXcH9A\"","value":"Y","key":"is_featured"},{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/VStyd4kXuLSIRpFXYvRPMBuYdDU\"","value":"Article","key":"TAG_DISPLAY_NAME"},{"visibility":"PUBLIC","kind":"drive#property","etag":"\"LIfz66WQFJW5vkUY9zfkRsF1GXw/PglkjP6d-2vMgJrovo3b02atA3g\"","value":"KM1100996","key":"kmid"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason to use the v2 API (and they do exist), you should probably use https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update .

For v3 at least, any properties you provide in your PATCH body are merged with the existing properties.

So...

> Start File: {foo:1}
>
> then Patch: {bar:2}
>
> leaves File: {foo:1, bar:2}

To delete a property, Patch it with null

> Start File: {foo:1, bar:2}
>
> then Patch: {bar:null}
>
> leaves File: {foo:1}

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, btw im using v2 of google drive api. It's okay now becuase the default behavior of the api will not remove other key-value pair in the list, it will only replace one with the same key as you passed.

Comment: what is your reason for using v2 instead of v3?

Comment: Because we are adapting our code to Google AppMaker which only supports v2.